# Use Jest to test Redux store

Tags: reactjs, redux, jestjs

I am new to Redux store test.
When I use Jest to test Redux store below, I get

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'redux-store' of undefined

TypeError: Cannot read property 'getState' of undefined**

It seems something relating to Redux doesn't work. How can I get around this and make this store test successful?
There are storeFactory and test shown below.

```
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware} from 'redux'
import { colors, sort } from './reducers'
import stateData from '../../data/initialState'

let console = window.console
let localStorage = window.localStorage

const logger = store => next => action => {
    let result
    console.groupCollapsed("dispatching", action.type)
    console.log('prev state', store.getState())
    console.log('action', action)
    result = next(action)
    console.log('next state', store.getState())
    console.groupEnd()
    return result
}

const saver = store => next => action => {
    let result = next(action)
    localStorage['redux-store'] = JSON.stringify(store.getState())
    return result
}

const storeFactory = (initialState=stateData) =>
    applyMiddleware(logger, saver)(createStore)(
        combineReducers({colors, sort}),
        (localStorage['redux-store']) ?
            JSON.parse(localStorage['redux-store']) :
            initialState
    )

export default storeFactory




import C from '../src/constants'
import storeFactory from '../src/store'
import { addColor } from '../src/actions'

describe("Action Creators", () => {

    let store

    describe("addColor", () => {

        const colors = [
            {
                id: "8658c1d0-9eda-4a90-95e1-8001e8eb6036",
                title: "lawn",
                color: "#44ef37",
                timestamp: "Mon Apr 11 2016 12:54:19 GMT-0700 (PDT)",
                rating: 4
            },
            {
                id: "f9005b4e-975e-433d-a646-79df172e1dbb",
                title: "ocean blue",
                color: "#0061ff",
                timestamp: "Mon Apr 11 2016 12:54:31 GMT-0700 (PDT)",
                rating: 2
            },
            {
                id: "58d9caee-6ea6-4d7b-9984-65b145031979",
                title: "tomato",
                color: "#ff4b47",
                timestamp: "Mon Apr 11 2016 12:54:43 GMT-0700 (PDT)",
                rating: 0
            }
        ]

        beforeAll(() => {
            store = storeFactory({colors})
            store.dispatch(addColor("Dark Blue", "#000033"))
        })

        afterAll(() => global.localStorage['redux-store'] = false)

        it("should add a new color", () =>
            expect(store.getState().colors.length).toBe(4))

        it("should add a unique guid id", () =>
            expect(store.getState().colors[3].id.length).toBe(36))

        it("should set the rating to 0", () =>
            expect(store.getState().colors[3].rating).toBe(0))

        it("should set timestamp", () =>
            expect(store.getState().colors[3].timestamp).toBeDefined())

    })

})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WebAPI `localStorage` is not available in a Jest context.
You can mock it for testing purposes by declaring a `setupTests.js` file in the root folder of your project.

```
const localStorageMock = {
    getItem: () => jest.fn(),
    setItem: jest.fn(),
    clear: jest.fn()
};

global.localStorage = localStorageMock;
```

To test your Redux related code, you can refer to the excellent [testing guidelines](https://redux.js.org/recipes/writing-tests) from the official Redux documentation.

EDIT: After a quick check, the setupTests.js file at root is a feature from the create-react-app CLI. It probably won't work if you are not using it.
But the idea is still here, localStorage is not available from Jest context.